# Is it possible to create suggestion for custom view?

Tags: android, android-custom-view

I am creating a custom view but I want to show suggestions to user just like other android views. Can I do that with custom views?

**For Example:**

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is possible to show custom options for your custom option using enum format in your `declare-styleable` tag for your custom view.

First, you declare your desired attributes in your attrs.xml file like this

```
<declare-styleable name="customView">
  <attr name="customOption" format="enum">
    <enum name="option1" value="0" />
    <enum name="option2" value="1" />
  </attr>
</declare-styleable>
```

Now get this `customOption` value in your customView like this

```
const val OPTION_1 = 0 //for readability
const val OPTION_2 = 1 //for readability
var customOption = OPTION_1

init {
  paint.isAntiAlias = true
  setupAttributes(attrs)
}

private fun setupAttributes(attrs: AttributeSet?) {
  val typedArray = context.theme.obtainStyledAttributes(attrs, R.styleable.customView, 0, 0)
  customOption = typedArray.getInt(R.styleable.customView_customOption, OPTION_1.toInt())
}
```

Comment: I'm getting error saying "values.xml:19:4: Invalid value 'null' for <enum>. Must be an integer."
How to suggest string values?

Comment: @RahulSaliya You've to share your code and your crash log, ask a new question. If possible, share code on GitHub. It would be easier to help.

Comment: It is happening because I'm trying string for suggestions and it only accepts integer.

Comment: Why do you want to use strings, enums are not supposed to store strings.